# add 2 words to query call insertIntoWPPOSTMETA

Tags: sql, database, phpmyadmin

I am using the below query for a single word in phpmyadmin:

```
call insertIntoWPPOSTMETA('episode 2');
```

But when I try to use it like this, it does not work:

```
call insertIntoWPPOSTMETA('episode 2','episode 2');
```

How can I use 2 words or more at the same time?

Comment: For most SQL databases, everything inside a set of parenthesis is part of one row of data. To get two rows, try `call insertIntoWPPOSTMETA('episode 2'),('episode 2');`.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling a function. Unless it is programmed to somehow accept more than one string, its not going to.

Edit:
You could write your desired query by concatenating the strings like this:

```
SELECT "call insertIntoWPPOSTMETA(" + column + ");"
FROM table
```

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? If your data comes from a table you can construct your 'call insertIntoWPPOSTMETA(value)' in a query, see my edit

Comment: Ah, I see. I guess you can only pass a character-separated string like `insertIntoWPPOSTMETA("episode 1;episode 2, episode 3")`. [Then split the string and loop through it's values.](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/split-a-string-and-loop-through-values-in-mysql-procedure)

Answer (score 0):

solved with

```
BEGIN

END
```

thanks to guys